# Image gallery in Jekyll with dinamic folder

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid

I would like to access the images in `assets/images/post/post-title-1` in the page `post-title-1` and 2 in the page 2.

I am trying to use something similar, but it doesn't show anything:

```
          {% for image in site.static_files %}
              {% if image.path contains '{{page.name}}' %}
                <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ image.path }}"/>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You used double brackets inside a for loop. That is not allowed. Try this:

```
 {% for image in site.static_files %}
   {% if image.path contains page.name %}
     <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ image.path }}"/>
   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```